# Trig general solution - getting different answer to book

Tags: trigonometry

For the question $$ tan(2x + 1.426) = -2.156 $$
I get the general solution $$x = n\pi/2 -1.281 $$
but the answer in the book is $$x=1.571n\pi-1.281$$

I've just started this general solution thing so I'm not sure 100% if the answer is a mistake or not...

Comment: the first answer $x = n\pi/2 - 1.281$ is correct according to ti-83.

Comment: What or who is ti-83?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: ti-83 is calculator by the texas instruments i use for simple mathematical calculations.

Comment: Oh ok. And I just realised something - 1.571 is $\pi/2$ so they probably forgot to take the extra $\pi$ symbol out.

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy: I would say you're right about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent function is periodic with period $\pi$.  Thus, $\tan x=\tan (x+n\pi)$ for all integer values of $n$.

Here, $\tan (2x+1.426)=-2.156$ implies that $\tan (2x+1.426+n\pi)=-2.156$.  Thus, we have

$$\begin{align}
\tan (2x+1.426+n\pi)&=-2.156\\\\
(2x+1.426+n\pi)&=-\arctan (2.156)\\\\
x&=-\frac12 \left(\arctan (2.156)+1.426+n\pi\right)\\\\
&\approx -1.2812538747+m\pi/2
\end{align}$$

where $m=-n$.  Inasmuch as $n$ can be any integer, negative or positive, $m$ can also be any integer.